# Is it possible to get the content of a file by path directly, in chrome application?

Tags: file, google-chrome-app

I'm writing some chrome application, and want to read some local files.

I didn't found any api from chrome that allowed to read a local file by path directly, but only a [chooseEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-chooseEntry) which would open a dialog to let user choose the directory first.

Is there any api of chrome can read a local file by path directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

For quite obvious security reasons.

You need express consent of the user via the `chooseEntry` dialog. Do note that you can retain the entry for reuse later, so you can only ask once.